# AMD Radeon 5/6/7xxx passthrough for virtualbox in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: radeon

I installed virtualbox on UBUNTU 12.04 derivative.

As usual there is no  direct Graphics card support.

I have an AMD radeon 6790 ...can i access the resources of this card via any mechanism to give my windies 7 guest with gfx capabilities...YES to play games etc.

Comment: Does your hardware support this?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Virtualbox and other virtual software emulates the hardware. Its not the original hardware. VirtualBox emulates a video adapter. In order to get a better visual experience you need to install the virtual box extras. But it won't be able to run games.

Some interesting reads,

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=409

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=16

Comment: Thank You. Its not a problem as most games run fine with Playonlinux. The reason i asked the question was that if i could run windows as guest on Ubuntu and then install all games on windows.....But this is clearly evident it wont happen anytime soon. Other than that PlayonLinux and wine has huge support for natively running stuff on linux(ubuntu). And more and more hardware vendors and manufacturers and game companies want to support linux (ubuntu) natively.  Thanks.